# Google Home Development without Google Cloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sdk, google-home

Is there a way to develop for the Google Home without having to use the Google Cloud or open an API to the public internet?

I'm in a restricted environment and can't just open up servers to the world without jumping through a lot of hoops. If I could do it all internally, it would save a lot of headache.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Due to the business environment we're in, solutions like ngrok aren't going to work (though for personal things, that's probably the approach I would take).

We ended up using TDD to write our code against test scenarios. This let us speed up development significantly, because whenever we went to actually test things on the actual device, 99.9% of the things worked the first time.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need the Google Cloud, but you need an API on the public internet. You can run everything on a web server, but of course, Google needs to see that server to be able to send you the requests.

For development, we have our own open source toolset [Bespoken Tools](https://bespoken.tools). It supports mainly Alexa for now but Google Assistant support is on the way. But from these tools, you can use the bst proxy to expose the server on your local machine inside the firewall (if your company lets you). A similar tool is [nGrok](https://ngrok.com).

Answer (score 0):

I started with Google Cloud, but the deployment process was taking too long for fast development.  Instead, I've been using the steps Google laid out for [node.js](https://nodejs.org/) and [ngrok](https://ngrok.com/).  It's MUCH faster to develop as I can make code changes and simply restart the node.js server each time which takes only 2 seconds.

Step by Step setup (easy):
https://developers.google.com/actions/tools/ngrok

Comment: Thanks. If I was doing this on my own, this is probably the approach I would take. Unfortunately, our IT security would be very unhappy if I tunneled a whole through our firewalls.